# how to verify version of files embedded in Windows Installer?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup

I have built Visual Studio Setup Project, and it contains some Merge Modules etc, now sometimes all dll files included in the project are not showing up as latest version.

After every build, I have to install every setup (5 of them) to check all dlls contain latest version files only.

Is there any API where I can analyze the content of MSI file and verify my dlls have correct version without doing install/uninstall?

Any COM interface will be helpful provided I can program some quick version check on c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Windows Installer Automation Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367809%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - that should give you what you need.

Also, there are tools out there like [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [LessMSI](http://code.google.com/p/lessmsi/), which allow you to peek inside the generated MSI files interactively.